# Syncing local laravel project with existing git repository

Tags: git, laravel

I am trying to set up a local working environment of a laravel project which is already on git. I have installed everything. [learning-laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/1) project is all set and working.

If i just clone the git repo i am able to use it, do everything on server but unable to execute locally, and that is obvious because most of the folders/file are in .gitignore file. Here is .gitignore file of the project

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/vendor
composer.phar
composer.lock
.env.*.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
.idea/
```

As i am relatively new to laravel and git. That is what i have done so far. I have created a laravel project through composer and tried to sync it with our git repo

```
cd project
git init
git remote add origin url_on_github
git pull
```

when i do `git pull` it seems to be fetching the code from git repo and after 100% gives some kind of git error

`There is no tracking information for the current branch.Please specify which branch you want to merge with.....`

Than i used `git pull origin master` but that also gives an error 
`error: Untracked working tree file '.gitattributes' would be overwritten by merge.` and there are of course many untracked files.

I also have tried much more but that was a summary of what i have been doing. So, i am bit confused while doing this. Any help will be largely appreciated to setup the local working environment for a laravel project which already has a git repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have to install Laravel first. You should:

- Clone locally the git repo from Github:

  ```
  $ git clone url_on_github
  ```
- Install Laravel packages dependencies with Composer:

  ```
  $ composer install
  ```
- Set permissions to some Laravel folders:

  ```
  $ chmod -R 775 app/storage
  ```

Comment: Great. It was really that simple, cannot believe. Basically i was trying in the reverse order. Installing dependencies first than syncing. Saved me hell of time thanks

Comment: Good answer, however, I think that app/storage doesn't exist anymore in laravel 5.2, please update the answer.

Comment: Please also add step 4~6:
(4) create a custom .env file
(5) php artisan key:generate
(6) php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do:

First go to Github and create a new empty repo.
Then doing the below steps.

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project --prefer-dist
$ cd my-project
$ git init
$ git remote add origin GITHUB_URL
$ git pull origin master
$ git status 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Init repo."
$ git push -u origin master
--- start to modify code from this point
```

All done! It just works for me everyday.

Comment: I tried to do exactly the same steps but the issue with my case was i cannot create an empty repo on Github. I have already the project setup and working. I need to setup local working environment for existing github laravel project. And the steps by @FR6 did the trick for me

Comment: @Adamnick to make it automatically, create your own webhook

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question (existing git repo, and getting the app to run locally). Please check if question has changed in the meanwhile.