# sync laravel code with github

Tags: github, laravel-5.1, github-for-windows

I want to sync my code to my github repo, so anytime I update my code it should be updated in the repo. Is there any proper and structured way of doing this.

Comment: Have you followed any [GitHub tutorials](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)? Where are you getting confused?

Comment: i followed the second answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059639/syncing-local-laravel-project-with-existing-git-repository) but it is for one time or manually doing it every time. @Chris

Comment: use git over cli or a the github client and commit and push your code! If you do not have enough knowledge about git, learn it! https://laracasts.com/series/git-me-some-version-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I am doing it now

**1**

```
$ cd my-project
$ git init
$ git remote add origin GITHUB_URL
$ git pull origin master
$ git status 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Init repo."
$ git push -u origin master
```

then just repeat following steps

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Init repo."
$ git push -u origin master
```